# After I reinstalled my app on Android my Firebase token is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Google Firebase. All works fine, until I reinstall the app on my phone. Then this code>

```
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

returns `null`.

That is my code in "FirebaseInstanceIDService"

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {




    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    registerToken(token);




}

private void registerToken(String token) {



    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token",token)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("URL")
            .post(body)
            .build();

    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Before I changed my Activity that runs first on App open it worked very good. But now it doesn't work.

Thank you for your answers, and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I think I found the error. The Service starts after the Activity ask for the token. How I can start the service before the Activity?